# Expat proposal needs just 1 more question with >10 score! Can you help?

Tags: discussion, immigration-questions, expat-questions

For some time there's been  the problem of immigration questions on here, and there's been tentative hope of an immmigration.SE - and indeed, there's an [Immigration/Expat](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates) proposal.

Now, [said immigration/expat proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates) has actually reached enough followers, but needs more questions / votes for those questions to reach the next level.

In mid July, they needed 11 more questions to reach 10 votes or more. As of today, that's down to just 1 question needing 10 votes! Can you help vote some of them up?

Comment: I upvoted 5 questions (that's the limit).

Comment: Only 3 more needed now! Just needs a couple more people to head over to Area51 and vote...

Comment: And it's there! [Commitment time!](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732?phase=commitment) (Not sure if we want to do a new question for that, or edit this one, @MarkMayo?)

Comment: @Gagravarr oh definitely a new question - go for it!

Comment: @Gagravarr needs 200 committers.  Has 2.  This could take a while.

Comment: @Gagravarr maybe suggest in your question that people promote the hell out of it - reddit, twitter etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've used my votes long ago. It seems that it's not much needed to start an extremely boring commit phase, in which many proposals die or are converted into zombies.

Maybe it wouldn't be bad idea to start an Expat-chat to join this 200 people together?